# Зачем разработчики придумали фазу всплытия и фазу захвата для событий?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Не понимаю насчет того, зачем придумали фазу всплытия и фазу захвата для событий. ранняя модель событий DOM 0 была понятной: щелкнул мышкой на объекте-узле и выполнился какой-то кусок кода (который запихали в функцию). и все. а с этими всплытиями и перехватами мне не понятно, зачем их вообще придумали. какой смысл затрагивать НЕСКОЛЬКО кусков кода (функций-обработчиков) при ОДНОМ событии? какие есть самые простые и хорошо иллюстрирующие примеры применения этого?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самый простой и часто используемый пример - это [делегирование событий](http://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation). Вы устанавливаете один обработчик событий на родительский элемент, а внутри проверяете реальный целевой элемент события и реагируете соответствующим образом.

Это позволяет не только экономить память (один обработчик вместо многих), но и обрабатывать события на динамически создаваемых элементах, не назначая для них обработчик руками.

А вот простой пример использования нескольких обработчиков одного и того же события:

> Всплытие – это удобно. Не прекращайте его без явной нужды, очевидной и архитектурно прозрачной.
>
> Зачастую прекращение всплытия создаёт свои подводные камни, которые потом приходится обходить.
>
> Например:
>
> 1. Мы делаем меню. Оно обрабатывает клики на своих элементах и делает для
>    них stopPropagation. Вроде бы, всё работает.
> 2. Позже мы решили отслеживать все клики в окне, для какой-то своей функциональности, к примеру, для статистики – где вообще у нас кликают люди. Например, Яндекс.Метрика так делает, если включить соответствующую опцию.
> 3. Над областью, где клики убиваются stopPropagation, статистика работать не будет! Получилась «мёртвая зона». Проблема в том, что stopPropagation убивает всякую возможность отследить событие сверху, а это бывает нужно для реализации чего-нибудь «эдакого», что к меню отношения совсем не имеет.

[Источник](http://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F)